# How to import android.support.v7.* (appcompat) to AIDE

Tags: android, import, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Anyone know how to import android support to AIDE compiler app

Comment: Navigate to the `app/` folder, click "Add to project...", then select "com.android.support: appcompat-v7:+". Alternatively, open the `build.gradle` file in that same folder, and add it manually.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of time spent searching and with the help of Alan Downie ( Cudos to you! ) here is the instructions to use AppCompatActivity with version 27.+ of the support library. It is important to use the latest support libraries as older libraries have bugs which are fixed in later versions. Ok here goes.

1.Create a new project in AIDE.

2.Add the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+` support library. ( Using the 'Add to Project' option available in your project folder within the Aide app.) 
3.Change the following items in your `build.gradle` file, which is also available in your project folder.

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.+"
```

add the following to you dependencies section.

```
compile ('android.arch.core:runtime:+') {
       force = true
}
```

The above is needed as there is an issue with Aide and AppCompatActivity not loading all the required libraries. This will be fixed soon hopefully.

4.Go to your res/values folder and click on styles.xml and change the following.

Change

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

To

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

5.Do the same as 4 to your res/values-v21 folder. (Important!)

6.Just to be clear, below is what your build.gradle file should look like for a basic out of the box working Aide project using the latest supported support libraries. I hope you find this post useful.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.+"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.your.appname"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile ('android.arch.core:runtime:+') {
       force = true
       } 

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

PS. Don't forget to change the extends Activity to extends AppCompatActivity  in your MainActivity.java file and don't copy and paste the above, change the values in your existing build.gradle file instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me (after refresh libs and build).